# Error when writing to xls file - apache poi multithreading

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, apache, apache-poi

I have the following problem. I am parsing a big XML file ( about 100 MB ) - and then, after I process the data I am writing the outputs to an XLS file.

The processing is done in parallel(using an ExecutorService), and all the threads are writing to the same Workbook.

The exception that I got is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.RowRecordsAggregate.getEndRowNumberForBlock(RowRecordsAggregate.java:219)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.RowRecordsAggregate.createIndexRecord(RowRecordsAggregate.java:469)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.visitContainedRecords(InternalSheet.java:637)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getBytes(HSSFWorkbook.java:1466)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1380)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1366)
at sample.Controller.buildSpreadsheet(Controller.java:295)
at sample.Controller.generateXLS(Controller.java:325)
... 58 more
```

The thing is that sometimes works without any problem, but sometimes crashes with this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe empty cells in the excel sheet?

Comment: More information regarding the code and other thing would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI does not support multiple threads writing to the same Workbook, so this will fail, just as you have found

Apache POI quite happily supports multiple threads all writing to their own Workbooks

You need to re-work your logic so that there is only ever one thread writing to a given Workbook, or so that you apply your own Synchronisation logic to prevent multiple of your threads writing at the same time

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will re-work on the logic of the application to use only one thread.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` means that you try to use a member/method of an object which was `null`. It is probably due to empty cells. You need to check

> RowRecordsAggregate.java:219

and see what throws the exception. For instance, if there `foo.bar` is used, but `foo` is `null`, then you need something like this:

```
if (foo == null) {
    foo = "";
}
//Do something with foo.bar
```